# Trouble getting dynamically created UI elements in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I create some UI elements in a for loop and I set their Name attributes to `name+i` where `i` is the loop counter. Later, if I try to get an element by name that was created in the for loop, the UI element is not found. What am I doing wrong?
Edit:
Ok, here is the code:

```
WrapPanel panel = new WrapPanel();
panel= (WrapPanel)FindName("panel");
Image img;

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    img=new Image();
    img.Name="name"+i;
    img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("someimg.png", UriKind.Relative));
    panel.Children.Add(img);
}

//where img could not be found. However, at this point, all the images are present in panel.Children
img= (Image)FindName("name1");
```

Edit 2:
Ok, I solved the problem, I just had to use the RegisterName method also. Thanks everyone...

Comment: After creating controls, have you added those into parent control? It would be better if you can post the code block so that forum can help you better.

Comment: WPF/UWP and XAML were design with the MVVM pattern in mind. While you can use other approaches, doing so misses about 90% of it's power and runs into issues at every other corner. Accessing UI Elements to get data is generally frowned upon. It ties you down to thise one UI. In MVVM you would not need to. You have your ViewModel Properties, with Binding keeping those Synchronous to the View Elements. I wrote a intro into MVVM a few years ago and highly recommend learning it https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: We can't tell, because we can't see any code. This is why creating an MCVE that reproduces your problem is so important. It helps you isolate the issue, which might result in you finding the solution yourself, and if not, you can put it in your question so we can help you. For more info, http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve

Comment: @user1672994 I added the code. Thanks for the help...

Comment: @Will I added the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what the problem was. I also had to use `RegisterName` method after adding a child to a parent.